# HangFire for On-Premises and azure should always run

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iis, hangfire

I'm going to include HangFire in my Web Application, which should run as well as on-premises as Azure.

I've read the following documentation: [Making ASP.NET application always running](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html)

What happens if you don't change the `applicationHost.config` file like description? It seems like, that the implementation of `IProcessHostPreloadClient` (in this case `ApplicationPreload`) is called by Windows Process Activation (even if I don't change applicationHost.config). Is that right? If not, how can it works as azure application? Because by azure you don't have to change the file `applicationHost.config`.

In other words, is there a guarantee that my recurring tasks and delayed jobs will always be enqueued, if I don't change applicationHost.config?

Comment: As far as I know, the azure application will not stop, if there are any request to access it, so it may be something wrong with HangFire running. Besides, we couldn't add applicationHost.config in the azure to enable always on, we could just change the setting in application setting in azure.